# How to change size of first parameter into environment?

Tags: environments, fontsize

I would like the first parameter of this environment to appear in a larger font size, but it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
\newenvironment{ct}[1][\unskip]{%
    \large {#1}
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}%  
    \altfont
    \noindent
    \center
    \color{red}
    \bfseries
    \ignorespaces
}
{%
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}%
    \par
}
```

In the document:

```
\begin{ct}{I want that more big}
    \crr {CEC 394, 538-540, 2119:}
\end{ct}
```

As you can see, *I want that more big*  is not more big:

[image]

Comment: A couple of things: What is `\altfont` and `\crr`? You define the `ct` environment with only an *optional* argument `[..]`, yet you supply it with a *mandatory* argument `{..}`. Finally, `\large` is a font *declaration*, affecting everything from that point on. If you want it to have a local effect, use scoping: `{\large ... }`, not `\large{...}`.

Comment: @Werner `\altfont` is a macro that would select a certain font type for that block. And `\crr` is another macro with which I wanted to format only part of the block. I am starting in LaTeX and am a bit confused between environment and macro. What I want in summary is that both lines are in red, with the same type of font, but that the first line has a larger size. Maybe there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, with some adjustments to your definition. There are a number of choices for the size of the first argument... I've chosen `\Large`, but you can also try with `\LARGE` and `\Huge`. If you want something larger than that, one can resize it using `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` (from [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\altfont}{\sffamily}
\newcommand{\crr}{\textit}

\newenvironment{ct}[1]{%
  % \begin{cr}{#1}
  \par% Start a new paragraph
  \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space above
  \centering% Alignment
  \altfont% Font
  \bfseries% Weight
  \color{red}% Colour
  {\Large #1\par}% Change to \LARGE or \Huge
  \ignorespaces
}
{% \end{cr}
  \par% Start a new paragraph
  \addvspace{\baselineskip}% Space below
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{ct}{I want that more big}
  \crr{CEC 394, 538-540, 2119:}
\end{ct}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, although I had to make an adjustment in the definition of `altfont`, because I had indicated a fixed size and for that reason it was not accepting the application of `\large` or `\LARGE`. Thanks a lot.